# Returning multiple values with CompletableFuture.supplyAsync

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, completable-future

I am writing a program to download historical quotes from a source. The source provides files over http for each day which need to be parsed and processed. The program downloads multiple files in parallel using a `CompletableFuture` using different stages. The first stage is to make a Http call using `HttpClient` and get the response.

The `getHttpResponse()` method returns a `CloseableHttpResponse` Object. I also want to return a url for which this http request was made. Simplest way is to have a wrapper object having these 2 fields, but i feel it is too much to have a class just to contain these 2 fields. Is there a way with `CompletableFuture` or Streams that I can achieve this?

```
  filesToDownload.stream()
                 .map(url -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> this.getHttpResponse(url), this.executor) )
                 .map(httpResponseFuture -> httpResponseFuture.thenAccept(t -> processHttpResponse(t)))
                 .count();
```

Comment: What's the cost of a class having these 2 fields?

Comment: @DidierL That's hard to quantify. Or rather: It depends. *Iff* (if and only if) it is **only** supposed to be locally, a simple **local** `class Pair { URL uri; Response response; `}` could be fine. Otherwise, I also think that creating a dedicated class for something like this may be overkill. It's a pity that there is no class like a `Pair<A,B>` in the standard API. In doubt, one has to create an [own pair class](https://github.com/javagl/Common/blob/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/common/Tuple2.java) (the code of this class can be considered as "public domain", it's trivial).

Comment: Note that using `map` for side effects is an abuse of the Stream API. This may break completely in Java 9, if `filesToDownload` is a Stream source with a known size (like almost every Collection). Then, `count()` will simply return that known size… As a fun fact, if you stop abusing `map` operations, the problem will disappear.

Comment: @Marco13 java has a `Pair<A,B>` class (but its part of javafx) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Pair.html

Comment: When you say you "_want to return a url_" what will you use it for? Don't you simply need to build a map of url -> future or something like that?

Comment: @DidierL - I want to extract file name to use to store the downloaded file. What i require is that once the response is received and that stage completes use that response to write the file to disk, I really don't need a map here a simple pairing object is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not clear why you want to bring in the Stream API at all costs. Splitting the `CompletableFuture` use into two `map` operations causes the problem which wouldn’t exist otherwise. Besides that, using `map` for side effects is an abuse of the Stream API. This may break completely in Java 9, if `filesToDownload` is a Stream source with a known size (like almost every Collection). Then, `count()` will simply return that known size, without processing the functions of the `map` operations…

If you want to pass the `URL` and the `CloseableHttpResponse` to `processHttpResponse`, you can do it as easy as:

```
filesToDownload.forEach(url ->
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> this.getHttpResponse(url), this.executor)
                     .thenAccept(  t -> processHttpResponse(t, url))
);
```

Even, if you use the Stream API to collect results, there is no reason to split the `CompletableFuture` into multiple `map` operations:

```
List<…> result = filesToDownload.stream()
  .map(url -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> this.getHttpResponse(url), this.executor)
                               .thenApply(   t -> processHttpResponse(t, url))  )
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
  .stream()
  .map(CompletableFuture::join)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this will collect the `CompletableFuture`s into a `List` before waiting for any result in a second Stream operation. This is preferable to using a parallel Stream operation as it ensures that *all* asynchronous operations have been submitted, before starting to wait.

Using a single Stream pipeline would imply waiting for the completion of the first job before even submitting the second and using a parallel Stream would only reduce that problem instead of solving it. It would depend on the execution strategy of the Stream implementation (the default Fork/Join pool), which interferes with actual policy of your specified executor. E.g., if the specified executor is supposed to use more threads than CPU cores, the Stream would still submit only as much jobs at a time as there are cores — or even less if there are other jobs on the default Fork/Join pool.

In contrast, the behavior of the solution above will be entirely controlled by the execution strategy of the specified executor.

Comment: The idea of using steam api was to use the parallel processing provided by streams out of box as the number of files is going to be large. I will eventually get rid of count and use collect method to collect the output from last stage. So I am going to change thenAccept to thenApply to read the file and return the file path. The next stage will then read this file and save it to database and return the number of records that were processed. This number of records processed will be collected to a map of url and number of records processed.

Comment: Also there are examples all over to use map function to call the methods on completable future, e.g. http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-completablefuture-in-action.html. The map function is just using the input and transforming it to what is required, i am not sure if there is anything wrong using it this way.

Comment: Well, things are different, if you are going to collect the results. Still, the idea to do this in a (parallel) Stream operation has no point, as you are already initiating asynchronous operations. And splitting the chained calls to the `CompletableFuture`, which already has a fluent API, into multiple `map` operations still makes no sense. It complicates the code with no benefit. Using a single `map` operation with a chain of CF ops, you will be able to use a `URL` in subsequent stages, just like in my `forEach` example.